# How to add values for alternative cells in Excel column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In an Excel sheet, I want to add values A1, C1, E1 and so on.

I tried with

```
 =IF(MOD(ROW(), 2) = 0, 1, 0)
```

I want to add values of H2,J2,L2,N2,P2 and all alternative cells. 
Like that I2,k2,m2,o2 abd all alternative cells. Image attached.

[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y54sy.png)

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you perhaps post an example of your existing data and expected output?

Comment: Without more information my guess is you meant to use: `=IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2)=0,"",1)` which outputs: `A1=1`, `B1=""`, C1=1` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Example]

One way of solving your issue is to use **SUMPRODUCT**.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:L1)*(MOD(COLUMN(A1:L1),2)<>0))
```

Replace `A1:L1` with the relevant range on your worksheet.

It will be better if you can provide some sample data and expected output next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an array formula. (I'll use A1:E1 as the example range). First we need to assign either 1 or 0 to each cell.

```
  Mod(Column(A1:E1),2)=0
```

Then we multiply each cell by that 1 or 0 to give either the cell value or zero as the result

```
  a1:e1*mod(column(a1:e1),2)=0
```

Then we Sum them

```
 =SUM(A1:E1*(MOD(COLUMN(A1:E1),2)=0))
```

and finally we enter this as an array formula by entering it using Control Shift Enter

Comment: Should be `MOD(...)=1` to get columns A, C, ... . You could also use `ISODD` instead of `MOD`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the range you want to add is `A1:A10` try this `FormulaArray`

```
= SUM( $A$1:$A$10 * ISODD( ROW( $A$1:$A$10 ) ) )
```

or this if the range is `A1:Z1`

```
= SUM( $A$1:$Z$1 * ISODD( COLUMN( $A$1:$Z$1 ) ) )
```